# Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I want to build a web app using spring boot and react js (followed the tutorial [here](https://www.blackpepper.co.uk/blog/using-create-react-app-with-spring)).
In pom.xml I added:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Copy frontend production build to resources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/app/build/</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When executing mvn clean package, i get the errors below. Maven version is 3.0.5.

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.0.5: Failure to
>   find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:3.0.5 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

EDIT:
I have changed the in maven-resources-plugin tag, the maven version to 3.0.2 but now i get errors on:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>Install Node and Yarn</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>yarn install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>Frontend production build</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>run build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <nodeVersion>v7.2.0</nodeVersion>
        <yarnVersion>v0.18.0</yarnVersion>
        <installDirectory>.mvn</installDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/app</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

ERROR:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:install-node-and-yarn
>   (Install Node and Yarn) on project ema: The plugin
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.2 requires Maven version
>   3.1.0 -> [Help 1]

Comment: you need to change version to 3.0.2, since it's latest. After that you need to restart maven build by using mvn package -U, for example. -U will redownload your dependencies.

Comment: also, in tutorial it uses 3.0.1 version, so you might want that version instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, your problem is here:

```
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.5</version>
```

This version is intended to convey the version of the `maven-resources-plugin`, not maven itself.

The most recent version applicable here is `3.0.2`.

I also recommend that you upgrade your entire maven installation to the most recent 3.5.0 release.

Comment: If i put <version>3.0.2</version> i get an error here  <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId> (v 1.2)

Comment: I get: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:install-node-and-yarn (Install Node and Yarn) on project ema: The plugin com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.2 requires Maven version 3.1.0 -> [Help 1]
when changing to 3.0.2

Comment: Getting Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem then i change code        1.5.9.RELEASE it is working now perfectlty

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is your `maven resource plugin repository` version isn't valid.

Change your `pom.xml` file's  repository to this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```